# analog of the method `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively`

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, assertj

Can you please suggest an analog of the method `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively` from the library AssertJ.
Because this method is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed deprecated, the [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(java.lang.Object)) indicates to use [`usingRecursiveComparison()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.19.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#usingRecursiveComparison()) instead which is documented here: https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison